# How to export all mails form specific folder from Outlook to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have macro which exports all data from Outlook **INBOX** to Excel along with time and date, but I need to set up to a particular folder to be copied in a same way.

How do I setup to specific subfolder?

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyToExcel()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWB As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object
    Dim rCount As Long
    Dim bXStarted As Boolean
    Dim enviro As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim olItem 'As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strColA, strColB, strColC, strColD, strColE, strColF As String

    ' Get Excel set up
    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))

    'the path of the workbook
    strPath = enviro & "\Documents\Book1.xlsx"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    If Err <> 0 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened  ... "
            Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        bXStarted = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    On Error Resume Next
    ' Open the workbook to input the data
    ' Create workbook if doesn't exist
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
        xlWB.SaveAs FileName:=strPath
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

    On Error Resume Next
    ' add the headers if not present
    If xlSheet.Range("A1") = "" Then
        xlSheet.Range("A1") = "Sender Name"
        xlSheet.Range("B1") = "Sender Email"
        xlSheet.Range("C1") = "Subject"
        xlSheet.Range("D1") = "Body"
        xlSheet.Range("E1") = "Sent To"
        xlSheet.Range("F1") = "Date"
    End If

    'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
    rCount = xlSheet.Range("B" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row

    ' needed for Exchange 2016. Remove if causing blank lines.
    rCount = rCount + 1

    ' get the values from outlook
    Set objOL = Outlook.Application
    Set objFolder = objOL.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Set objItems = objFolder.Items

    For Each obj In objItems
        Set olItem = obj

        'collect the fields
        strColA = olItem.SenderName
        strColB = olItem.SenderEmailAddress
        strColC = olItem.Subject
        strColD = olItem.Body
        strColE = olItem.To
        strColF = olItem.ReceivedTime


        ' Get the Exchange address
        ' if not using Exchange, this block can be removed
        Dim olEU As Outlook.ExchangeUser
        Dim oEDL As Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList
        Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient

        Set recip = Application.Session.CreateRecipient(strColB)

        If InStr(1, strColB, "/") > 0 Then
            ' if exchange, get smtp address
            Select Case recip.AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType
                Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry
                Set olEU = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser

                If Not (olEU Is Nothing) Then
                    strColB = olEU.PrimarySmtpAddress
                End If

                Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olOutlookContactAddressEntry
                    Set olEU = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser

                    If Not (olEU Is Nothing) Then
                        strColB = olEU.PrimarySmtpAddress
                    End If

                Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry
                    Set oEDL = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList

                    If Not (oEDL Is Nothing) Then
                        strColB = olEU.PrimarySmtpAddress
                    End If
            End Select
        End If
        ' End Exchange section

        'write them in the excel sheet
        xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = strColA
        xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = strColB
        xlSheet.Range("c" & rCount) = strColC
        xlSheet.Range("d" & rCount) = strColD
        xlSheet.Range("e" & rCount) = strColE
        xlSheet.Range("f" & rCount) = strColF

        'Next row
        rCount = rCount + 1
        xlWB.Save
    Next

    ' don't wrap lines
    xlSheet.Rows.WrapText = False

    xlWB.Save
    xlWB.Close 1
    If bXStarted Then
        xlApp.Quit
    End If

    Set olItem = Nothing
    Set obj = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You are using ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder not inbox, what Level is the Subfolder is from inbox?

Comment: Yes sir,  ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder not inbox but even wen i am running form the code from subfolder it is exporting emails from inbox..sub folder is at 3 rd level from inbox sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You are using **[ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211818(v=office.11).aspx)** on your code, the [CurrentFolder Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211818(v=office.11).aspx)  represents the current folder that is displayed in the explorer, code should run on any [Active Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219397(v=office.11).aspx)- just navigate on any folder that you like to run the code on.*

*If you prefer to change then You need to modify the following lines of code to set up your specified  folder,*

```
' get the values from outlook
Set objOL = Outlook.Application
Set objFolder = objOL.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
```

*To something like this*

```
' get the values from outlook
Set objOL = Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
Set olNs = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("SubFolder Name Here")
```

> *<sub>See [Folder Object (Outlook) MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863890.aspx)  Use the Folders property of a NameSpace object or another Folder object to return the set of folders in a NameSpace or under a folder. You can navigate nested folders by starting from a top-level folder, say the Inbox, and using a combination of the Folder.Folders property, which returns the set of folders underneath a Folder object in the hierarchy,</sub>*
>
> *Example:*

```
GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("SubFolderName") _
                              .Folders("SubFolderName")
```

> *<sub>and the Folders.Item method, which returns a folder within the Folders collection.</sub>*